# Why has English become the global language?

Tags: language, world, english-language

I love the English and English.

I am truly fascinated by the expansion of the English language across the globe.
According to linguists all languages are great and unique.
If it is a fact, why English has become global language setting aside all other languages

Is it because of colonization or is it because of the felicity of expression and the resourcefulness of the language?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98368/discussion-on-question-by-jagatha-v-l-narasimharao-why-has-english-become-the-gl).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Professor [David Crystal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Crystal) has written a whole book on this, but it is possible to provide a reasonable answer without going to great lengths. First, though, it would help to define what a global language is. Why, for example, is English widely considered to be *the* global language when there are [far more native speakers of Mandarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers)?

Crystal, in *[English as a Global Language](http://culturaldiplomacy.org/academy/pdf/research/books/nation_branding/English_As_A_Global_Language_-_David_Crystal.pdf) (Cambridge, 2nd edition, 2003)*, defines a global language thus:

> A language achieves a genuinely global status when it develops a
>   special role that is recognized in every country....the notion of
>   ‘special role’ has many facets. Such a role will be most evident in
>   countries where large numbers of the people speak the language...

but

> mother-tongue use by itself cannot give a language global status. To
>   achieve such a status, a language has to be taken up by other
>   countries around the world. They must decide to give it a special
>   place within their communities, even though they may have few (or no)
>   mother-tongue speakers.

This, Crystal goes on to say, can be done in one of two ways: either the language is given official status or

> It becomes the language which children are most likely to be taught
>   when they arrive in school, and the one most available to adults who –
>   for whatever reason – never learned it, or learned it badly, in their
>   early educational years.

The specifics of Crystal's definition may be disputed by other academics (see '[*The Handbook of Language and Globalization*](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/The_Handbook_of_Language_and_Globalizati.html?id=g8vbLTzxHpkC&redir_esc=y)') but few (if any) within the mainstream would argue that English isn't a global language, even if they do not agree on what exactly that means.

---

On 'Why English?', Crystal provides this principal reason, applicable not just English now but other languages in the past:

> A language has traditionally become an international language for one
>   chief reason: the power of its people – especially their political and
>   military power.

That has, historically, been the initial stage, but it takes more:

> It may take a militarily powerful nation to establish a language, but
>   it takes an economically powerful one to maintain and expand it. This
>   has always been the case, but it became a particularly critical factor
>   in the nineteenth and twentieth centuries, with economic developments
>   beginning to operate on a global scale, supported by the new
>   communication technologies – telegraph, telephone, radio – and
>   fostering the emergence of massive multinational organizations...
>
> Any language at the centre of such an explosion of international
>   activity would suddenly have found itself with a global status. And
>   English,.... was apparently ‘in the
>   right place at the right time’.... By the beginning of the
>   nineteenth century, Britain had become the world’s leading industrial
>   and trading country. By the end of the century, the population of the
>   USA (then approaching 100 million) was larger than that of any of the
>   countries of western Europe, and its economy was the most productive
>   and the fastest growing in the world. British political imperialism
>   had sent English around the globe.... During the
>   twentieth century, this world presence was maintained and promoted
>   almost single-handedly through the economic supremacy of the new
>   American superpower. Economics replaced politics as the chief driving
>   force. And the language behind the US dollar was English.

Crystal develops the last part of the above later in his book:

> In the late nineteenth century and the early twentieth it was the
>   language of the leading economic power – the USA. As a result, when
>   new technologies brought new linguistic opportunities, English emerged
>   as a firstrank language in industries which affected all aspects of
>   society – the press, advertising, broadcasting, motion pictures, sound
>   recording, transport and communications.

Both Crystal and [Salikoko S. Mufwene](https://linguistics.uchicago.edu/faculty/mufwene) draw parallels with the Roman empire and Latin (while acknowledging that Latin was international rather than global), though Mufwene places a particular emphasis on colonization:

> Much of the impetus that today’s globalization has given to the spread
>   of English is also largely attributable to the earlier role that
>   colonization played in expanding the language geographically and
>   demographically.

*Source: 'Globalization, Global English, World English(es)', in Nikolas Coupland (ed.), '[The Handbook of Language and Globalization](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/The_Handbook_of_Language_and_Globalizati.html?id=g8vbLTzxHpkC&redir_esc=y)' (John Wiley & Sons, 2011)*

What can also be taken from this is that different regions and countries have had very different experiences and histories with English. Not only did Britain not colonize the entire world, the colonization, for example, of [Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Australia#Colonisation) was very different to that of [Ghana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_Coast_(British_colony)#Colonialism). Thus, while many similar factors can be ascribed to most countries or regions, the extent of their roles in the spread of English can vary greatly.

At first glance, one might consider films and music to be important, even critical, in English becoming a global language. However, while they have certainly contributed (especially in facilitating learning for those with the desire to do so), they would have been unlikely to have had much impact on their own. Witness, for example, the [widespread exposure to Bollywwod films](https://www.ibtimes.com/bollywood-west-africa-nigerias-love-fascination-indian-cinema-video-1169057) in West Africa over several decades; whilst some of the more fanatical fans have memorized the (mostly) Hindi dialogue, it has not led to them actually learning the language (personal experience of Mali and Burkina Faso since the early 1980s backs this up). Nor did my Danish grandparents ever learn any English (OK, 10 words at most), despite listening to British and American music, and seeing mostly British TV series almost daily on TV, for many decades. In short, except in rare circumstances, movies and music are at most two among many other factors in the spread of English.

Of greater importance were (and are) computers and the internet. They were at the start primarily developed and spread by Americans, and then became a means by which millions could more easily access and study a language which could help them (for example) get a better job. But, as Crystal observes, the effect the internet will have on English as a global language in the future is hard to predict:

> In a few generations’ time, the Net will not be like anything we know
>   today. Automatic speech synthesis and recognition will be routine, and
>   (notwithstanding the difficulties described on p. 27) more use will be
>   made of automatic translation. The arrival of high-quality immediate
>   translation facilities will have a major impact on the use of English
>   (or any lingua franca) on the Net.

A number of other reasons have been put forward as to why English has become a global language, mostly summarized in this [History of English](https://www.thehistoryofenglish.com/issues_global.html) article under the section *Is English Appropriate for a Global Language?*, but the author concludes that

> the intrinsic appeal of English as a world language is probably
>   overblown and specious, and largely based on chauvinism or naïveté. It
>   is unlikely that linguistic factors are of great importance in a
>   language's rise to the status of world language,...

(This site has a useful [sources and links](https://www.thehistoryofenglish.com/sources.html#Books) page for those who wish to explore the history of English further.) Crystal himself states:

> A language does not become a global language because of its intrinsic
>   structural properties, or because of the size of its vocabulary, or
>   because it has been a vehicle of a great literature in the past, or
>   because it was once associated with a great culture or religion. These
>   are all factors which can motivate someone to learn a language, of
>   course, but none of them alone, or in combination, can ensure a
>   language’s world spread. Indeed, such factors cannot even guarantee
>   survival as a living language – as is clear from the case of Latin,
>   learned today as a classical language by only a scholarly and
>   religious few. Correspondingly, inconvenient structural properties
>   (such as awkward spelling) do not stop a language achieving
>   international status either.

Comment: Nothing about Hollywood & Rock and Roll?

Comment: I'm still working on this answer (and trying not to make it too long!), but one has to be careful not to overstate Hollywood; while it is a factor, films are dubbed in many countries.

Comment: @axsvl77: There are a number (presumably large, though I have no data) of people to whom Hollywood and rock & roll are at best irrelevant (or indeed, something to be actively avoided), yet who still use English for other reasons.

Comment: I woud disagree about economic power being the main cause of English dominance.  It's rather scientific & technological power.  Most of the industrial revolution was centered around Britain.  In the late 19th century that had started to shift to the US.  WWII and its prelude, which caused many prominent scientists to flee Germany, only hastened the process.

Comment: @jamesqf I don't think there's a disagreement here. Crystal (and others) see science & technology as part of, if not integral, to economic power.

Comment: Also `A language does not become a global language because of its intrinsic structural properties` But the intrinsic structural property of Mandarin Chineese being a tonal language, and as such almost unlearnable for non-tonal-language-native-speakers, will probably prevent Mandarin becoming a global language in the future.

Comment: @Bregalad Whilst I would agree with you from my personal perspective (I've tried and failed miserably!), 'almost unlearnable' is probably putting it a bit strongly. After all, to many Asians in particular, English pronunciation is just as challenging to them as mandarin is to an English, French, German etc speaker. In short, how difficult a foreign language is to learn depends a lot on one's mother tongue.

Comment: "In a few generations’ time, the Net will not be like anything we know today. Automatic speech synthesis and recognition will be routine, and (notwithstanding the difficulties described on p. 27) more use will be made of automatic translation. The arrival of high-quality immediate translation facilities will have a major impact on the use of English (or any lingua franca) on the Net." I've worked in AI-related fields and I disagree. People don't like to rely on a translator to communicate

Comment: @David That is undoubtedly true now to some extent at least, but will it always be the case if translators improve significantly? As someone who has worked in the field of language teaching for 25 years, I've seen first-hand the impact that translators have had. Many students (I can't say whether or not it is the majority) use translators, often to comic effect (as I'm sure you can imagine), but it also true (as you say) that many people don't like to rely on them.

Comment: @LarsBosteen I mean, maybe for closely related language we are not that far away from using them for effective and accurate communication. But try translating from Norwegian to Mandarin and back. You will see that there is still a huge way to go

Comment: @David I certainly wouldn't disagree with your last comment - there is indeed a long way to go.

Comment: @Bregalad Not really. English-as-a-second-language is very often a separated language on its own. If the USA crashes out as a superpower and China takes its place in a hundred years a Colombian and a Dane could be communicating in a not-really-tonal chinese that no chinese native could understand, just as today many english monolinguals can't understand two non-native english speackers talking between them.

Comment: It's interesting to compare Russian, which was the elite language in the communist world (from East Germany to large parts of Asia) until the fall of the Soviet Union, for a variety of cultural and political reasons (including giving education in the USSR to those from friendly countries). Today it has largely been usurped by English and national languages, excluding in Russia itself. https://www.foreignaffairs.com/articles/russia-fsu/1998-01-01/language-follows-power-linguistic-free-market-old-soviet-bloc

Comment: @StuartF The article is from 1998. Russian is currently being introduced in Syrian schools as a #1 foreign language (the fact that probably supports the article you quote, not contradicts it - I could only read the first few paragraphs and refrained from "subscription"). An interesting fact is that a number of nowadays leaders of the so-called third world received their education in USSR and can still speak good Russian, after 30-odd years after their graduation...

Comment: @Lars Bosteen: But English (or Latin in the Middle Ages) does not need to be spoken to be useful as an international language of science & technology, or business &c.  In fact, I - an American who grew up just a couple hundred miles from New York City - have considerable trouble understanding even  the speech of actors in NYC-based sitcoms, let alone southerners, many British accents, Indian English...  But I have no trouble reading what people from those places write.

Comment: I do not know why this question was migrated from Linguistics when David Crystal, a famous linguist dealt with this topic.Even the questiom is very straight, it was kept on hold.There is nothing to edit my question.Since it has got 6 up votes, it is not too broad or out of topic

Comment: @JagathaVLNarasimharao It's not really my place to comment on why linguistics migrated the question as I'm not on that site, but it clearly has a historical basis so it is at least on topic here. On it being put on hold here, I already [posted a question](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3953/what-happened-to-democracy-on-history-se) on our meta about this, including (among other points) your point about 6 upvotes (as against 5 votes to close).

Comment: @Lars Bosteen.Thank you very much for your efforts.Now the question is open

Comment: On the topic of Chinese: it used to be the international language of East Asia, spoken (and written) by the intellectuals in non-tonal speaking Japan and Korea at the very least. So imho there’s nothing stopping a tonal language from being a global one even when most speakers of it have non-tonal native languages.

Comment: It boils down, I think to two things: First, and most important, "The right place at the right time".  Second, English is a reasonably flexible, reasonably learnable language not owned by anyone, not even England.

Answer (score 1):

We owe the dominance of English to the [British Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Empire).

> Decades, and in some cases centuries, of British rule and emigration have left their mark on the independent nations that arose from the British Empire. The empire established the use of English in regions around the world. Today it is the primary language of up to 460 million people and is spoken by about one and a half billion as a first, second or foreign language.
>
> The spread of English from the latter half of the 20th century has been helped in part by the cultural and economic influence of the United States, itself originally formed from British colonies.

As you may be aware, at its greatest extent the British Empire [covered more than one quarter of the world's land area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_empires), significantly bigger than the next-biggest Mongol Empire which covered "only" 18% of the world.

Comment: You must mean "*more than a quarter of Earth's land surface*". More than 70% of the Earth;s surface is ocean, and the British Empire never controlled anything like the vast majority of the rest.

Comment: Fun fact: the dominance of English in diplomacy, science, trade, etc came in mid 20th century, ie at the dawn of the British Empire. If nowadays dominance is due to a single country / event than it is much more the emergence of US as global superpower.

Comment: @Greg I think Allure is saying that the US used to be part of the British Empire too. Might be right.

Answer (score 0):

Throughout times multiple languages were the dominant ones in Europe. 
Mostly it was as follows:

- Greek - because of Greek philosophy, crafts and conquests of Alexander the Great.
- Latin - because of Roman Empire and Roman law.
- French - Because of the philosophy, Versailles, and the French revolution
- German - because of German technology, science and philosophy
- And, finally, English.

As late as first half of XXth century it was German which was the dominant language. Scientific papers were written in German, German was the most taught foreign language in the USSR, etc...

But everything changed with Nazism. German language earned a kind of stigma. Some people in Europe would shake if they heard some German speech around.

In the USSR, in particular, the share of people learning German dropped considerably after WWII.

Another factor was that before WWII most Jews in Europe spoke Yiddish which is close to German to such extent that in the Austro-Hungary Jews were classified as German-speakers. It was definitely easy for them to communicate in German. And many scientists were Jewish (Einstein, Ehrenfest, Friedman, Minkowski etc).

But in the course of WWII many Jews were killed and those who were not
decided to abandon Yiddish in favor of Hebrew, and German in favor of English as many scientists emigrated to the USA.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98341/discussion-on-answer-by-anixx-why-has-english-become-the-global-language).

Comment: Greek was never a dominant language in *Europe*.  Something like 98% of Alexander's conquests were not in Europe.

Comment: Greek was a language of _trade_ around the Mediterranean, and of some elites in that area (even in Rome...).

Comment: @CMonsour What was the language of the Eastern Roman Empire?

Comment: I disagree with German ever being a truely international language. In the beginning of the XXth century, French was way more used than German for diplomacy or trade

Comment: @David The language of the Eastern Roman Empire was a mixture of Latin and Greek until 600 or so.  (For example, the Corpus Iuris Civilis was written in Latin,)  After that it was Greek.  But the Eastern Roman Empire never dominated Europe, nor was Greek a lingua franca in Europe outside its borders.  Greek was a dominant language in the Near East, but that's not Europe.

Comment: @C Monsour At ancient times Greek was spoken in Spain, France, Italy, Balkans, Crimea and Tanaica. Etruscan, Celtic and Germanic peoples adopted Greek alphabet for their languages. In Macedon, Thrace, Illiricum Greek replaced the local languages completely.

Comment: @Anixx Adapting someone's alphabet doesn't mean their was the dominant language....  Greek was spoken in very specific parts of Spain, Italy, etc.

Comment: @David, German was the language of physics and engineering.

Answer (score 0):

If one were to board a time machine and turn the historical clock back to the year, 1900, one would notice that when traveling around nearly half the world's lands....the British Flag, was flown on diverse territories throughout the globe.

During this time, the Austrian, as well as the Ottoman Empires were essentially..."on their way out", as major imperial powers.  The Spanish Empire, was pretty much confined to the History books by the beginning of the 20th century and the Tsarist Russian Empire was becoming increasingly anachronistic-(whereby a generation later, its "fate would be sealed" by The Bolsheviks).  The French Empire, however, was still quite powerful and ubiquitous throughout much of the world and in a way, was the only remaining Empire that rivaled the British 100 plus years ago. Yet, in terms of the historical longevity and global reach of the French language, its influence and presence would be eclipsed by the English language beginning in the postwar period nearly 80 years ago. Why was this the case?....the answer....The United States of America.

Historically, there were various empires who helped to create the Modern civilization of America...-(i.e. the Spanish, the Dutch, the French and of course...the British).  For reasons that are too lengthy and complex for this site, let's just say that the British/Anglican cultural influence, became the more dominant presence in the continental United States over a period of centuries. This was primarily due to settlement, conquest, homesteading, ethnic cleansing of Native Indian populations spanning from Jamestown, Virginia and Eastern Massachusetts at the beginning of the 1600's, until the 1960's, with Hawaii becoming the 50th U.S. state.  Throughout this long stretch of American History, Anglo-American civilization was growing, winning and dominating the continental United States....this also included, the growing dominance, as well as the ubiquitous use and widespread presence of the English language.

By the beginning of the postwar period in the late 1940's, both the centuries old French and British Empires, were "on their way out" and their unofficial heir....was the United States.  With the proliferation of Russian-Soviet Communism throughout Eastern Europe and elsewhere around the world, coupled with the nearly indomitable presence of the U.S. military on both the European and Pacific "Theaters" during the Second World War, which ended with the devastating atomic bombings of Hiroshima and Nagasaki, Japan....it was clear to the world, that there was "a new sheriff" or "a new kid in town" and that new "sheriff" or "new kid" on the global "block", was the United States of America and with it.....the widespread utilization of the English language.

In other words, it is the historic connection between the widespread presence of British imperial rule during the early part of the 20th century, followed by the (unofficial) American heirdom to British imperial rule during the middle part of the 20th century, whereby the English language's worldwide influence would spread to nearly every corner on the planet...lasting into the present-day.

If one were to do a comparative linguistic study on which languages were the most dominant and influential worldwide-(over the centuries), languages, such as Ancient Persian/ Farsi, Greek, Latin, Arabic, Mongolian, Turkish, Russian, Portuguese, Spanish, Dutch (and possibly, German), would almost certainly top the list. Yet, each of these languages, are still secondary to the much larger reach that the French language and especially, the English language, have had on Contemporary Global civilization.

Comment: [The adoption of English as the international standard for radio commiination for aviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation_English) likely played a part.